# vb.net Serializing Collections unable to add a collection to object?

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm trying to generate some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
"@type": "MessageCard",
"sections": [
    {
    "activityTitle": " Request",
        "facts": [
        {
                "name": "name1",
                "value": "Value"
            },
            {
                "name": " Date:",
                "value": "Value Date"
            }
        ],
    "text": "Some Test."
    }
 ],
"potentialAction": [
    {
        "@type": "ActionCard",
        "name": "Add a comment",
        "inputs": [
            {
                "@type": "TextInput",
                "id": "comment",
                "isMultiline": true
            }
         ]
     }
   ]
}
```

I performed a paste special into VS and it generated the class structure for me as such:

```
Public Class MessageCard
 Public Property type As String
 Public Property context As String
 Public Property summary As String
 Public Property themeColor As String
 Public Property sections() As Section
 Public Property potentialAction() As Potentialaction
End Class
```

I'm trying to add the sections to the object as such:

```
Dim m as New MessageCard  
Dim s As New List(Of Section)
        s.Add(s1)
        s.Add(s2)
        m.sections = s
```

The compiler complains that it cannot convert a list of Sections into a Section.  Did the class get generated incorrectly, or am i constructing it incorrectly?

Comment: `sections As Section()` and `potentialAction As Potentialaction()` The robots have trouble with arrays.  But a List(of Section) still wont store to a section array.  You can type the properties as Lists

Comment: @plutonix I'm still stuck on this, i changed `sections as Section()` then trying to do `m.sections(0) = s` but getting a null reference.

Comment: you will need to create the array instance (or List instance) either create the instance in the constructor or as part of the declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your JSON is not quite complete and the Classes you show wont create that JSON.

As posted, that JSON simply shows a `Sections` and `potentialAction` class which are not related in any way.  An enclosing  `[ ... ]`  is needed to represent the `MessageCard` class containing the two of them.

> [{
>     "@type": "MessageCard",
>     ...
>   }]

Next, the class you have shows all sorts of things not present in the JSON: `context`, `summary` and `themeColor` for instance.  I assume those might be missing for brevity, but it is confusing.  There is also 2 other Types missing which **are** in the JSON, `Fact` and `Input`.

Corrected, the classes should be:

```
Public Class MsgCard
    <JsonProperty("@type")>
    Public Property ItemType As String
    Public Property sections As List(Of Section)
    Public Property potentialAction As List(Of Potentialaction)

    Public Sub New()
        sections = New List(Of Section)
        potentialAction = New List(Of Potentialaction)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Section
    Public Property activityTitle As String
    Public Property facts As Fact()
    Public Property text As String
End Class

Public Class Fact
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property value As String
End Class

Public Class Potentialaction
    <JsonProperty("@type")>
    Public Property ActionType As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property inputs As Input()
End Class

Public Class Input
    <JsonProperty("@type")>
    Public Property InputType As String
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property isMultiline As Boolean
End Class
```

Notes

- You did not specify a JSON serializer, so this is prepared to JSON.NET as recommended by Microsoft.
- `@type` is an illegal property name, so the `JsonProperty` attribute is used to create an alias.  I also used less confusingly redundant names.
- You may want to change `Fact` and `Input` to `List(Of T)` if you will be creating and pushing them into the class object as well.

Finally, for the actual question you asked, most of the automatic class generators have trouble with arrays (even VS).

```
Public Property sections() As Section
' should be:
Public Property sections As Section()
```

That simply declares that `sections` will be an array, it does not create the array.  Normally this is not a problem because the Serializer/Deserializer will create the array.  To allow code external to the class to add to them, you probably want to use a `List` as the classes above do, then create the instance in the constructor:

```
Public Sub New()
    sections = New List(Of Section)
    potentialAction = New List(Of Potentialaction)
End Sub
```